# boost::log time_based_rotation doesn't work as expected

Tags: c++, logging, boost

boost::log time based rotation doesn't work as expected.
I would like that the log rotates at 23:59:59 every day. This happens only if
a `new log line` is written in log file. Otherway the log doesn't rotate.
Size rotation works well.

I use these is my code:

```cpp
 keywords::time_based_rotation = sinks::file::rotation_at_time_point( 23, 59, 59 ),
 keywords::rotation_size = 8 * 1024 * 1024, 
 keywords::auto_flush = true,
 keywords::file_name  = base_path_ + ( base_path_.back() != '/' ? "/" : "" ) + base_name_
                                      + ( file_ext_.front() != '.' ? "." : "" ) + file_ext_,
 keywords::target_file_name = base_path_ + ( base_path_.back() != '/' ? "/" : "" ) + base_name_
                                             + "_%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S" + ( file_ext_.front() != '.' ? "." : "" )
```

Log doesn't rotate if no new lines are written.

Comment: That's by design. The solution is to fix your expectation. Or, you can reopen the logs after midnight, or somesuch.

Comment: Also, look at [`std::filesystem::path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) or [`boost::filesystem::path`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#class-path) to avoid the error prone name kludges

Comment: What is the use-case for non-lazy time-based rotation? Ensure that something in your software writes  log entry every day after 23:59:59 if there is such case.

Comment: The use case is that I need a tar with all the day logs. The tar is done by a crono script